# Can I pass an array of symbols to a macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm parsing some data from string maps to a different structs, each with their own set of member variables. The setup could be something like this:

```
struct AStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
};


map<string,string> aMap;
aMap["a"] = "3";
aMap["b"] = "2.42";

struct BStruct
{
    string a;
    char b;
};

map<string,string> bMap;
bMap["a"] = "asdf";
bMap["b"] = 'k';
```

As there are many structs but few contained primitives, I have created a helpful set of templated parsing functions:

```
template <typename T>
void parse(string origin, T& dest);
```

Now, in order to prevent myself from having to define a different function to assign the values to each struct, I can use a macro, something like this:

```
#define ASSIGN(map, dest, param0Name, param1Name) \
    dest.param0Name = map[#param0Name]; \
    dest.param1Name = map[#param1Name]; \
```

and assign like so:

```
AStruct myA;
ASSIGN(aMap, myA, a, b);
```

This is a big help. But in reality my structs all have a different number of members, requiring a new macro to be defined in each case.

**Is there a way I can pass an array of symbols to the macro and iterate through those?**

Something like this:

ASSIGN(map, dest, { param0Name, param1Name, param2Name })

Comment: You may want to have a look at Boost.PP for this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say with macros you're out of luck. Indeed there are variadic macros that allow to pass ahead args, but that is all you can do with them.

I tried

```
#define B(x, y) int x = y;
#define A(x, y, ...) B(x, y)  A(__VA_ARGS__)

void f()
{
  A( g, 1, h, 2); 
}
```

doesn't work obviously. Proposals to add things to preprocessor are common but are routinely rejected.

Comment: You are right, there is no mechanism to access each element without a variadic function.

Comment: As useful as it would be for me in this case, it's fair enough that there's a reluctance to add things to the preprocessor as it would introduce many use cases that would make things more difficult to understand.